# Calculating percentile based on binning input

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

Hi Currently I want to try to create a function to calculate a percentile based on binning input,
says that i have this datasets from histogram.

```
given:  
hist = [10, 15, 4]   
edges = [0.5, 6, 12, 25]  
perc = 5
```

I would like to return the percentile based on binning of perc, so the return would be something like this

```
perc = 5
return percentile(data,0),
percentile(data,.25),
percentile(data,50),
percentile(data,75),
percentile(data,100)
```

output : [0.5, 4.4875, 7.8, 10.7, 25]

I had tried using pandas.qcut(data,perc) but seems like the cut is not correct

Comment: Please provide a minimal and complete example of your problem and explain why your solution does not provide the expected result. Actually your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, this should work:

```
def percentile_binning(hist, edges, percentages):
    hist_cumsum = np.cumsum(hist)
    hist_sum = hist_cumsum[-1]
    hist_cumsum_norm = hist_cumsum / hist_sum
    indxs = np.digitize(percentages, hist_cumsum_norm)
    bins_reduction = np.append(np.array([0]), hist_cumsum)[indxs]
    vals_between_edged = percentages * hist_sum - bins_reduction
    edged_diff = edges[1:] - edges[:-1]
    edged_diff = np.append(edged_diff, 0)
    percentage_diff = edged_diff[indxs]
    percentage_edge_value = edges[indxs]
    percentage_bins_sizes = np.append(hist, hist_sum)[indxs]
    result = percentage_diff * vals_between_edged / percentage_bins_sizes + percentage_edge_value
    return result
```

**Input:**

```
hist = np.array([10, 15, 4])
edges = np.array([0.5, 6, 12, 25])
percentages = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
print(percentile_binning(hist, edges, percentages))
```

**Output:**

```
[ 0.5     4.4875  7.8    10.7    25.    ]
```